# How I can log the reason why I am unable to save a file into S3 in my Laravel app?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-10

I am saving a file into S3:

```php
$status = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('s3')->put('test.txt',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

if(!$status){
  throw new \RuntimeException("Unable to save a file");
}
```

But upon failure I am unable to diagnose why I cannot save a file. I mean if `$status` is `false` I do not know why is false because `put` does not throw an exception.

Therefore, I want to log the errors the internal S3 SDK returns upon failure. How can I achieve this?

The existing flag does not give me much info to log regarding the failure.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by changing the setting `throw` into true at `config/filesystems.php`:

```php
return [

    // Existing settings here ommited for simplicity

    'disks' => [

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => true, // <<< This must be true
        ],
    ],
    // Existing settings here ommited for simplicity
];
```

Then you can do the following:

```
try{

   $status = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('s3')->put('test.txt',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
} catch(\Exception $e){
  report($e);
  throw new \RuntimeException("Unable to save a file");
}
```